# Apply discount to bundle based on selected options

Tags: discount, bundled-product, bundle

I have about 300 bundle products consisting of a set of wall art products. Each option represents a certain design, and each option has 2 possible selections: a framed print and an unframed print of the same design.

From the front end, the user can either select all framed prints, or all unframed prints for a single bundle (mixing is not allowed).

I would like to apply a discount only if the user selected the framed prints, but not if they selected the unframed prints.

What are my options? I've taken a short look at the [Product Bundled Discount](https://marketplace.magento.com/magedelight-bundlediscount.html) extension, but it doesn't seem to support this.